# Scala date formatting from Mysql

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0

Having trouble with date formatting, I have the code below:

BUT i get [IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date] in Play 2.1-RC3

```
def formatDate(indate: Date) : String = {
        val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        val datedate = dateFormat.format(indate)
        datedate
    }


    val fdate = Extrastuff.formatDate("2012-10-08 15:16:56.0")
```

Comment: try `val fdate = Extrastuff.formatDate(new Date())`, basically you are passing a `String` where `Date` is expected

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right then method formatDate accepts object of type Date (indate: Date), but you are trying to use it with a string.

Comment: Hi thanks, I just need to format that string/date to remove the .0 millisecond

Comment: Then you might try accepting date as string, parse it as date and then formatting it with method you posted. Also I would highly recommend using joda-time library for all date/time manipulations.